How to display row numbers in MAUI ListView or CollectionView?
I have MAUI page with ViewModel that contains an array of type string. The name of the array field is Ingredients. This is how i'm trying to display this field:
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Ingredients}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                <Label Text="..." 
                       FontAttributes="Bold" 
                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>

                <Label Text="{Binding .}" 
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       Margin="10,0,0,0" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

But how can i display the row index in the first label?
So the output should be:
1 Item1
2 Item2
3 item3


The common approach is to have an ItemToIndexConverter, but, this has the following flaws:

It's not efficient for large lists, O(N²)

Anyhow, to get you started, here's a demo but has the following assumptions:

Ingredients is either a Collection or a List
Assumes strings are unique, otherwise, if there are duplicates it returns the first match
Your use case requires the index to begin from 1, whereas the typical solution is a 0-based index (feel free to add 1 to the return value in the converter below)

<Label
    FontAttributes="Bold"
    Text="{MultiBinding {Binding Ingredients, Source={Reference mainPage}},
                        {Binding .},
                        Converter={local:IndexToItemConverter}}"
    VerticalOptions="Center" />

Then, you could implement IndexToItemConverter as follows:
public class IndexToItemConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => values[0] is IList<string> l && values[1] is string s ? l.IndexOf(s) : -1;
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

